# How to install lombok in IntelliJ Idea if I am not able to install plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lombok

I am working on a project and currently we are trying to use Lombok for our application. So I tried to install Lombok in STS per documentation, and it was straightforward to install. And then I also wanted to install Lombok in Intelli Idea. So I followed the steps

```
Go to File > Settings > Plugins

Click on Browse repositories...

Search for Lombok Plugin
```

But due to some restrictions on plugin downloads within my company network, I am not able to see Lombok plugin in search and so cannot install it.

So I wanted your help to know if there is a way to install and use Lombok plugin in Intelli J Idea like a work around similar to installing in STS.

I can see a lot of tutorials which mentions to install the plugin which in my case is not possible.

example: https://medium.com/danielpadua/java-lombok-2984afff3e0a

Please help me with your thoughts.

Comment: Some comapnies forces the traffic to go through a proxy. Check out if that's the case at your organization. This can be configured in IDEA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Magnilex, mentioned in the comments, the proxy settings in the Intelli J Idea 2020.3 were disabled. So I have enabled the proxy settings by clicking on

> Settings -> Plugins -> click settings icon -> click Auto detect proxy settings -> click OK and then I am able to search for Lombok plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to download Plugin directly and install it, choose the lombok version corresponding to your IDEA version.

lombok plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/versions

Then Go to File > Settings > Plugins -> Install plugin from disk

[Manage plugins - Install plugin from disk](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#install_plugin_from_disk)